# pmatrix and vdots are not aligned between rows

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, matrices

Consider the following code to create a matrix

```
\documentclass{svmult}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,trees,decorations,external,positioning,backgrounds}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  Y = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1  & 0 & \hdots & \hdots & 0
    \\
    1 & 0 & & & \vdots
    \\
    0 & 1 & \ddots & & \vdots
    \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots & \vdots
    \\
   \vdots &   & \ddots & 1 & 0 
    \\
    0 & \hdots & \hdots & 0 &  1 
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The output is the following

[image: output]

What I would like to correct is the fact that several ddots are not aligned in the sense there is no one straight line passing through these dots.
In particular, the diagonal dots of the third and fourth row and the 1 and 0 of the second last row are not aligned (ddot)

EdIT: Here is the class file is available here :
[class file](http://www.inrialpes.fr/FSR07/svmult.cls)

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ code. That's not the normal output, you have something else which is stretching the matrix vertically.

Comment: I edited but I wonder which package does this streching ?

Comment: swvnmult sets `\arraycolsep` to `1.5pt` whereas the normal article class sets it at `5pt`. Not sure why `svmult` does not, it may be because people are still using `eqnarray` (they really should not) and this `\arraycolsep` change makes `eqnarray` look less bad. I'd just add `\setlength\arraycolsep{5pt}` to the preamble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround, adding a small negative vertical space between  well-chosen rows. I also used `\hdotsfor{2}` rather than two consecutive `\hdots`.  To have similar  continuous or diagonal  vertical dots, you can use  the `nicematrix` package, based on TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation*}
  Y =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \hdotsfor{2}& 0
    \\
    1 & 0 & & & \vdots
    \\[-0.5ex]
    0 & 1 & \ddots & & \vdots
    \\[-0.5ex]
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots
    \\[-0.5ex]
   \vdots & & \ddots & 1 & 0
    \\
    0 & \hdotsfor{2} & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]